# Force delete a file using SSIS on a network location

Tags: ssis

I am facing a problem while deleting a file on a network location using SSIS, since its a zip file, contains monthly SQL Database backup file, so I need to delete the last month file before copying current month file.

May be there is some app which were using this file, I am not sure, but I wanna get rid of this file, so that I can copy new file.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You haven't mentioned an error or any specific difficulty that you have. Can you be more precise? If you're trying to delete a file that's in use then the usual approach is to find the process locking it and stop that process or have it close the file handle.

Comment: Its a production box, which create db backup file from raw data & upload it to different servers. Other processes monitor these locations & if found new backups, they start uploading these databases backup files to different servers. So its a process run every month, I have to delete the old file & put new file on the same locations every month. Some of the shared locations don't allow me to delete the file, So I have to ask  systems to restart those machine so that the file can be free and can be deleted. But I need some command in SSIS to delete these files even they are locked by some app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a file task and you should be able to delete pretty much anything on any location as long as you have the rights to do so.

Comment: File System Task is not working, Execution result shows, Access to the path "....." is denied. The path and file perfectly accessible, I can copy this file, but can't delete this file. I can even create another file on the same location and delete that new file.

Comment: If you can do all those operations, then its probably some other process thats accessing the file. I am afraid, if thats the case then there's nothing any other script or process could do. Its OS based control and out of scope for SSIS.

Comment: Probably I will use some other server for this purpose. Thanks for your help